# Get the values of posted array in servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, arrays, servlets

```
var schedule = [];

var data = { 
   'user_id' : '12', 
   'day_of_week' : 'Monday',
    'when' : 'start',
    'modified' : 'true'
 }

schedule.push(data);
var data = { 
   'user_id' : '13', 
   'day_of_week' : 'Tuesday',
    'when' : 'end',
    'modified' : 'false'
 }
schedule.push(data);
// schedule would have two objects in it
```

I am posting array to servlet using jquery ajax post request as below .

```
data :  {'myData':schedule},
url :"./myController",
```

Now how can I get array of objects and literate to get all the values? Each array object has   string, long and boolean type values. How can I get all the values by  iterating?

Comment: Have you tried some code? If yes then please share. If not then please try.

Comment: You should try some JSON deserializers like GSON/FlexJson

Comment: @sanbhat , Do i need to map model if i use gson ?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this

```
json.getJSONObject("myData").getString("your_values");
```